# Where does pandas_datareader get its data from?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I was working on a python program that calculates stock indicators. I used the get_data_yahoo function to get most of the info. But after some research, I found out that the yahoo finance API had been discontinued for quite some time now. So now I'm just curious on how pdr gets this info since it seems that most of the info I get from it is fairly accurate.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! We're not a research service - anything you can find by simply googling is something you should just look up on your own. Please see the guide to [ask], and feel free to ask again if you have a programming question!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

They provide further information in [their docs](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html), though the sources used by pandas-datareader are listed as follows

> Tiingo
>
> IEX
>
> Alpha Vantage
>
> Econdb
>
> Enigma
>
> Quandl
>
> St.Louis FED (FRED)
>
> Kenneth French’s data library
>
> World Bank
>
> OECD
>
> Eurostat
>
> Thrift Savings Plan
>
> Nasdaq Trader symbol definitions
>
> Stooq
>
> MOEX
>
> Naver Finance
>
> Yahoo Finance

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

What does 'calculates stock indicators' mean? Maybe this will help.

```
import pandas_datareader as web
import pandas as pd
 
df = web.DataReader('AAPL', data_source='yahoo', start='2011-01-01', end='2021-01-12')
df.head()

import yfinance as yf
aapl = yf.Ticker("AAPL")
aapl
 
 
# get stock info
aapl.info
 
# get historical market data
hist = aapl.history(period="max")
 
# show actions (dividends, splits)
aapl.actions
 
# show dividends
aapl.dividends
 
# show splits
aapl.splits
 
# show financials
aapl.financials
aapl.quarterly_financials
 
# show major holders
aapl.major_holders
 
# show institutional holders
aapl.institutional_holders
 
# show balance sheet
aapl.balance_sheet
aapl.quarterly_balance_sheet
 
# show cashflow
aapl.cashflow
aapl.quarterly_cashflow
 
# show earnings
aapl.earnings
aapl.quarterly_earnings
 
# show sustainability
aapl.sustainability
 
# show analysts recommendations
aapl.recommendations
 
# show next event (earnings, etc)
aapl.calendar
 
# show ISIN code - *experimental*
# ISIN = International Securities Identification Number
aapl.isin
 
# show options expirations
aapl.options
 
# get option chain for specific expiration
opt = aapl.option_chain('YYYY-MM-DD')
```